# Having access to both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of JVM

Tags: java, windows, registry

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I have 2 JVM's installed - 32 and 64 bit versions. When I have such in registry, I can execute only 32 bit JVM using double click:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\java.exe\shell\open\command 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" "%1"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\javaw.exe\shell\open\command
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

But I can still launch 64 bit JVM using bat files (even without "-d64" arg).

Now, if I remove `(x86)` in both keys, I can launch 64 bit JVM with double click regardless which javaw.exe I choose in "open with" menu and what do I have in PATH environment and I can't launch 32bit JVM using "-d32" arg in bat file (it says something like you don't have such, please install it). However, such arg as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin" is still valid.

**The question:** How can I choose which JVM version do I want to start without creating batch files and editing Windows registry every time?